getting error when try to send the two transactions combined for swap to jupiter sdk
i'm trying to send a two seperate swap transaction as one through the help of versioned transactions to solana network and in return i'm getting the error below
SendTransactionError: Transaction  resulted in an error. 
Request is too big.
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:6043:13)   
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5999:20) 
    at async ArbBot.executeSwap (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\bot.ts:549:20)
    at async Timeout._onTimeout (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\bot.ts:413:15) {
  signature: '',
  transactionMessage: 'Request is too big',
  transactionLogs: undefined
}

RangeError: encoding overruns Uint8Array
    at Blob.encode (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts:2294:13)
    at Structure.encode (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts:1205:26)
    at MessageV0.serialize (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\message\v0.ts:292:51)
    at VersionedTransaction.sign (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\transaction\versioned.ts:95:38)  
    at ArbBot.executeSwap (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\bot.ts:546:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Timeout._onTimeout (G:\PlutonRunningProjects\arbitrage_bot_backEnd\arbitrage_bot_backend\bot.ts:413:15)


The two transaction are going over the accepted limit of 1232 bytes.
To overcome this limitation,

Try using Jito bundles -> https://docs.jito.wtf/lowlatencytxnsend/

send the two instructions in separate transactions.


solana docs on transactions -> https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions#key-points

Thanks for the suggestion.i used jito-ts
